# Check all values of object in list are unique

Tags: java

I have the following POJO class with the following data members.

class name: History

```
private BigDecimal price;
private Event event;
private Date eventDate;
```

The POJO is stored in a `List`. How can I remove any object that has identical values for all data members?

Example:

Out list contains the following objects

History object 1

```
price = 2
event = "sold"
eventDate = "2/2/2000"
```

History object 2

```
price = 2
event = "sold"
eventDate = "2/2/2000"
```

History object 3

```
price = 5
event = "purchased"
eventDate = "2/2/2000"
```

In this case object 1 or object 2 should be removed.

Comment: Transform it to a `Set`, or use a `Set` from the get-go.

Comment: Override `equals` and/or `hashcode`, then add the list to a set.

Comment: @Turing85 when using a `Set` I should still override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods?

Comment: @david No. You even have to. Otherwise, the `Set` will not function correctly.